# Problems with header();

Tags: php

After writing and testing this file, `header("location: url");` won't work... i don't know what to do... here is the code:

HTML File

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Program</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <center>
                <br><br><br><br>
                <a id="question">10a + 4b + 9a + 1b</a>
                <br><br><br><br>
                <form action"php/q1.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="a" placeholder="00">a + <input type="text" name="b" placeholder="00">b<br>
                    <input type="submit" value"Next" id="start">
                </form>
                <br><br><br><br>
            </center>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP File

```
<?php
    $a = $_POST['a'];
    $b = $_POST['b'];
    $final = $a .. "a + " .. $b .. "b";
    if ($final = "19a + 5b") {
        setcookie("score", 1);
    } else {
        setcookie("score", 0);
    }
    header("location: http://www.example.com/go/algabra/simplifying/easy/q2.php");
    exit();
?>
```

Please don't ask me what this code is for!
I tryed to figure out, I have researched various different sites and I can't find anything.

PHP Version: PHP 7.1

Comment: Are you saying that you ran this code without understanding what it does? That doesn't sound good.

Comment: $final = $a .. "a + " .. $b .. "b";  syntax error ( double dots)

Comment: We don't have to ask where the code will be used as you already leaked that information in your code snippet.

Comment: When you say "doesn't work," what do you mean?  What behavior are you expecting, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: It should be setting a cookie (witch it is not doing) and then it should redirect to the next question witch it is not doing

Comment: you should use `if ($a == '19' && $b == '5')` currently, there's no need to use `$final`...

Answer (score 3):

It's probably getting an error before reaching the header line.

```
$final = $a .. "a + " .. $b .. "b";
```

should be

```
$final = $a . "a + " . $b . "b";
```

You probably want to make this fix also:

```
if ($final = "19a + 5b") {
```

to

```
if ($final == "19a + 5b") {
```

Also you're missing an equals sign after the word action in your html form.

Comment: I have use the changes defined... but it still won't redirect